# React. Fill a state array every N seconds, and only while its smaller than X length

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const TxContainer: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const [tx, setTx] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTx((oldArr) => [...oldArr, "tx" + Math.random()]);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [tx.length < 10]); //this useEffect still keeps pushing even if the array is bigger than 9

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tx.length);
  }, [tx.length]);

  let listTx = tx.map((data, index) => (
    <p key={index}>
      {index} {data}
    </p>
  ));
  return <React.Fragment>{listTx}</React.Fragment>;
};

export default TxContainer;
```

Im trying to create random strings and put them in an array until this array is 10. Whenever, its 10 it should start deleting the first element of the array to keep working and displaying new data, but thats another story.
The point is that its not stopping when it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing a compare like that in the dependency array of the `useEffect` it will only invoke it again, when the resulting value changes. Basically those dependencies mean "if this value changes in any way, call the `useEffect`". Besides that it's being called on mount and on unmount. So for your code to work as you intended you should pass to the dependency array a variable that your calculations depend on and pass the logic inside the `useEffet`.

Here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8rtanp) of the code that you described, of course I don't know if you want to use the same timeout or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (tx.length < 5) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTx(oldArr => [...oldArr, "tx" + Math.random()]);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000);
    } else {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTx(oldArr => [...oldArr.slice(1)]);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [tx.length ]);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: second useEffect is not needed. This effect runs first time and whenever array length is changed. when it reaches 11, clear the interval or remove first element.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setTx((oldArr) => [...oldArr, "tx" + Math.random()]);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000);
        if(tx.length === 11){
          setTx(prev=>prev.slice(1))
          // clearInterval(interval)
        }
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
 }, [tx.length]);
```